# snmp mib for netapp on debian squeeze

Tags: snmp, netapp, mib

Trying to get cacti drawing graphs on our netapp, I downloaded NETWORK-APPLIANCE-MIB.mib from http://www.oidview.com/mibs/789/NETWORK-APPLIANCE-MIB.html and copied it into /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/.

Stracing snmpwalk it looks like the file is successfully being read, but I'm still seeing **OIDs** and not **names** in my output.

```
$ snmpwalk -v 1 -c $community_string udp:$host_ip:161  .1.3.6.1.4.1.789.1.5.4.1.2
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.789.1.5.4.1.2.1 = STRING: "aggr0"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.789.1.5.4.1.2.2 = STRING: "aggr0/.snapshot"
...etc
```

Any hints as to else what I need to do to match the MIB file up with the snmp stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add it to the MIB path, [you need to load it](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/FAQ.html#How_do_I_add_a_MIB_to_the_tools_):

```
Secondly, tell the tools to load this MIB:

    snmpwalk -m +MY-MIB .....
        (load it for this command only)
or
export MIBS=+MY-MIB
        (load it for this session only)
or
    echo "mibs +MY-MIB" >> $HOME/.snmp/snmp.conf
        (load it every time)
```

Comment: Aha, that's helpful, thanks! So after seeing it work successfully with your instructions, since my goal is to make the mibs available to cacti, I added this line

`mibs +/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/NETWORK-APPLIANCE-MIB.mib`

to /etc/snmp/snmp.conf

Now snmpwalk is showing the names instead of numbers.  Cacti still isn't creating the graphs, but I guess that's a question for a different thread :-/